# Как получить данные из $resource

Tags: angularjs

Есть фабрика которая получает ссылку и возвращает(должна) данные

```
(function () {
angular
    .module('app.formBuilder')
    .factory('formDataService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return {
            data: undefined,

            /**
             * get data for form from server
             * @param url route with form data
             * @returns {json} JSON
             */
            getFromDataFromUrl: function (url) {
                this.data = $resource(url, {}, {
                    method: 'GET'
                }).get();

                return this.data;
            }
        }
    }]);
})();
```

В контроллере я ее получаю и передаю дальше в директиву и тд, как сделать чтобы директива и тд не писала что переменная не существует, а ждала ответа, и как собственно получить данные из $resource, когда делаю console.log в директиве скопа показывает что vm пустое, тк ответ приходит спустя 2секунды, и аж после в vm появляются данные из сервера

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.formBuilder')
    .controller('FormBuilderCtrl', FormBuilderController);

FormBuilderController.$inject = ['$state', 'formDataService'];

function FormBuilderController($state, formDataService) {
    var vm = this,
        formJsonUrl = $state.$current.initialize,
        formData = formDataService.getFromDataFromUrl(formJsonUrl);

    formData.$promise.then(function (response) {
        formData = response;
    });

    console.log(formData);

    vm.filterFormData = formData.filter || {};
}

})();
```

Comment: а где директива-то? можете предоставить пример на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)?

Comment: @Grundy уже решил) передал промисс в деректиру и в then выполнил привязку данных

Comment: тогда можете опубликовать свой ответ, либо закрыть вопрос. Кроме того - ангуляр умеет резолвить resource во view